# Mic input meter to detect audio/noise using Windows IoT Core UWP

Tags: audio, windows-iot

I am trying to make a VU Meter something that will show the noise or sound around the device with USB microphone attached to it. I tried following blog sample code but it works with hardware attached to Pi and then interacting with it through Windows SPI

https://blog.falafel.com/windows-iot-core-sensing-sound/

what I am trying to do is make an IoT UWP application (exactly like above) that will just monitor USB microphone connected to Pi and then show the level of audio. Preferably do not lock the microphone so that other threads can work on it for recording etc. Being a UWP that will work on Computer too.

I have been googling since yesterday and couldn't get much information. Any guidance is appreciated.